# a Racket problem about the accumulator-style recursion

Tags: racket

Using accumulator-style recursion, write a function
one-long-string that consumes a ListOfString and produces the
concatenation of strings in the list in the order they appear in the list.
That is, (one-long-string (list "Alice" "Bob" "Eve")
returns "AliceBobEve"

Comment: Please edit your question to include at least the start of the process of developing this function (eg write in a **signature**, **purpose statement**, and **stub definition**)

Comment: Are you familiar with how to used the 'named `let`' special form? I have checked, and it is supported by the Advanced Student language setting. Alternatively, a nested `(define)` should also work.

Comment: If you haven't done so already, I recommend solving the problem using naive recursion first, to show that you understand how to implement the basic tests, then re-work the function to use tail recursion via accumulation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notes (added later):

- Original question (quoted below) did not specify a particular Racket language, or provide an
  attempted solution, or indicate what sort of issue prompted the question.
- This answer will use Racket's [Beginning Student](https://docs.racket-lang.org/htdp-langs/beginner.html)
  language (BSL), and develop (in exhaustive detail) a simple "natural recursion" solution, followed by
  conversion to the requested "accumulator-style". BSL is used to focus attention on how using the design method
  enables solution development without requiring "leaps of intuition", or familiarity with advanced language.
- Readers may wonder how long it actually takes, meticulously following the design recipe with it's
  signatures, check-expect tests, template copying and editing, etc, to produce the finished function.
  The answer, for me, is about 10 minutes; for comparison, just "writing a function" (with signature and purpose)
  and repl checking examples, takes about half that.

> Using accumulator-style recursion, write a function one-long-string that consumes a ListOfString and produces the concatenation of strings in the list in the order they appear in the list. That is, (one-long-string (list "Alice" "Bob" "Eve") returns "AliceBobEve"

#### Get started

Using the [design recipe for writing functions](https://courses.edx.org/courses/course-v1:UBCx+HtC1x+2T2017/77860a93562d40bda45e452ea064998b/#HtDF), one starts with a function **signature** and **purpose**; these can be copied from the question above and pasted into a Racket function definition **stub** in the DrRacket definitions area:

```
(define (one-long-string los) ;; ListOfString -> String ; *stub* ;; *signature*
  ;; produce the concatenation of los strings in order  ; *purpose statement*
  "")                                                   ; *stub body* (valid result)
```

The next step is to add a minimal **example** in the form of a [`check-expect`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/htdp-langs/beginner.html#%28form._%28%28lib._lang%2Fhtdp-beginner..rkt%29._check-expect%29%29):

```
(check-expect (one-long-string empty) "")               ; *minimal example*
```

And then (with DrRacket's Language set to [Beginning Student](https://docs.racket-lang.org/htdp-langs/beginner.html)), **Run**:

```
The test passed!
>
```

#### Follow the recipe

Continue following the design recipe by selecting a **template** based on the argument type `ListOfString` -
copy it into the definitions area:

```
(define (fn lox) ;; ListOfX -> Y                  ; *template*
  ;; produce a Y from lox using natural recursion ;
  (cond                                           ;
    [(empty? lox) ... ]                           ; ...  = "base case value" ;; Y
    [else (....                                   ; .... = "inventory fn(s)" ;; X Y -> Y
           (first lox) (fn (rest lox))) ]))       ;
```

(There is a template for "accumulator-style recursion", but this answer will start with the simplest
ListOf template. The solution will be modified to accumulator-style later.)

Edit the template, replacing the generic names with the appropriate ones for this problem, to get:

```
(define (one-long-string los) ;; ListOfString -> String
  ;; produce the concatenation of los strings in order
  (cond
    [(empty? los) "" ]        ;; String
    [else (....               ;; String String -> String
           (first los) (one-long-string (rest los))) ]))
```

The placeholder `...` has been replaced by `""` by reference to the first example above.
Note that the signature of `....` has been deduced from the signatures of its arguments and result.

Comment out the stub (prefix it with `#;`), and **Run** again to confirm that `The test passed!`.
(Always run after any change to confirm that everything still works, and fix any typos immediately.)

Add another example:

```
(check-expect (one-long-string (list "Alice")) "Alice")
```

and **Run**: the error message confirms that the placeholder `....` needs to be replaced.

(This test *could* be made to pass by adding `(define (arg1 x y) x)` and using `arg1` for `....`,
but one can see that something better is likely to be needed.)

The replacement for `....` will have signature `String String -> String`; we don't have such a
function, but checking [Strings in Beginning Student](https://docs.racket-lang.org/htdp-langs/beginner.html#%28part._htdp-beginner._.Strings%29)
for suitable functions yields the following possibilities:

```
; format        ;; String Any    -> String        ; *inventory* (all functions with
; string-append ;; String String -> String        ; signature String String -> String)
```

Consider another example:
`(check-expect (one-long-string (list "Alice" "Bob")) "AliceBob")`
given "Alice" and "Bob", one can produce "AliceBob" with `string-append`, ie the example can be written:

```
(check-expect (one-long-string (list "Alice" "Bob")) (string-append "Alice" "Bob"))
```

This suggests that `....` should be `string-append`; one can now add a final example:
`(check-expect (one-long-string (list "Alice" "Bob" "Eve")) "AliceBobEve")`
**Run** again, and the (non-accumulator) function is complete:

```
#;
(define (one-long-string los) ;; ListOfString -> String ; *stub* ;; *signature*
  ;; produce the concatenation of los strings in order  ; *purpose statement*
  "")                                                   ; *stub body* (valid result)

(check-expect (one-long-string empty) "")               ; *minimal example*

(define (one-long-string los) ;; ListOfString -> String
  ;; produce the concatenation of los strings in order
  (cond
    [(empty? los) "" ]
    [else (string-append
           (first los) (one-long-string (rest los))) ]))

(check-expect (one-long-string (list "Alice")) "Alice")
(check-expect (one-long-string (list "Alice" "Bob")) (string-append "Alice" "Bob"))
(check-expect (one-long-string (list "Alice" "Bob" "Eve")) "AliceBobEve")

All 4 tests passed!
>
```

#### Accumulator style

As mentioned earlier, there is a template for "accumulator-style recursion", which uses
features of [Advanced Student](https://docs.racket-lang.org/htdp-langs/advanced.html)
language. Why would one use a version of the function incorporating an accumulator?
A common reason is to put the recursive call in tail position.

To explore this style, first try to edit the template to be tail-recursive:

```
(define (fn lox) ;; ListOfX -> Y           ; *template*
  ;; produce a Y from lox (tail recursive) ;
  (cond                                    ;
    [(empty? lox) ... ]                    ; result ;; Y
    [else (fn (rest lox))                  ; tail recursion
           .... (first lox)                ; (where do these go?)
          ]))                              ;
```

This can't be right (the placeholder `....` and `(first lox)` don't fit) but continue by
replacing the generic names:

```
(define (one-long-string los) ;; ListOfString -> String
  ;; produce the concatenation of los strings in order
  (cond
    [(empty? los) ... ]                    ;; String
    [else (one-long-string (rest los))
            .... (first los)               ; ?
            ]))
```

The recursive `one-long-string` call in the partially filled-in template is now in tail position,
with argument `(rest los)` so that it can deal with all the elements of los,
but to make progress in producing the result the function must do something with `(first los)`.
Where can this be fitted in?
One way to resolve this question is to introduce an argument: with the additional argument,
`one-long-string` (now renamed to `one-long-string-with-arg`) has a place in the recursive
call to hold `(first los)`:

```
(define (one-long-string-with-arg los arg) ;; ListOfString X -> String
  ;; produce the concatenation of los strings in order, using extra arg
  (cond
    [(empty? los) (... arg) ]              ;; String
    [else (one-long-string-with-arg (rest los) (.... arg (first los)))
          ]))
          
(define (one-long-string los)              ;; ListOfString -> String
  ;; produce the concatenation of los strings in order
  (one-long-string-with-arg los .....))
```

`one-long-string` now just calls `one-long-string-with-arg`, supplying `.....` for `arg`.
Recalling the first two examples:

```
(check-expect (one-long-string empty) "")
(check-expect (one-long-string (list "Alice")) "Alice")
```

one can see that a simple replacement for `.....` is `""`, and for `(... arg)`
just `arg`. As before, the other examples suggest `string-append` for `....`.
The rôle of `arg` in `one-long-string-with-arg` is to *accumulate* a "result so far" value,
so it is renamed `rsf`, and the complete accumulator style solution is:

```
#;
(define (one-long-string los) ;; ListOfString -> String ; *stub* ;; *signature*
  ;; produce the concatenation of los strings in order  ; *purpose statement*
  "")                                                   ; *stub body* (valid result)

(check-expect (one-long-string empty) "")               ; *minimal example*

(define (one-long-string-acc los rsf) ;; ListOfString String -> String
  ;; produce the concatenation of los strings in order using rsf accumulator
  (cond
    [(empty? los) rsf ]
    [else (one-long-string-acc (rest los)
           (string-append rsf (first los))) ]))
           
(define (one-long-string los) ;; ListOfString -> String
  ;; produce the concatenation of los strings in order, using accumulator
  (one-long-string-acc los ""))

(check-expect (one-long-string (list "Alice")) "Alice")
(check-expect (one-long-string (list "Alice" "Bob")) (string-append "Alice" "Bob"))
(check-expect (one-long-string (list "Alice" "Bob" "Eve")) "AliceBobEve")

All 4 tests passed!
>
```

(to be continued)

Comment: ty。 but this problem need to use "advanced student"

Comment: Interesting. So can you edit your question to add the function signature and stub (in advanced student format)? (or alternatively provide more information about why the question is asked?)

Comment: If I am not mistaken, "Advanced Student" is a superset of "Beginning Student with List Abbreviations", so what works in the latter should also work in the former. I've tested it, and `(check-expect)` certainly does work in "Advanced Student".